# Understanding units in $Z_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In $Z_{12}$ , the elements $1$, $5$, $7$, and $11$ are units. But how and why? I can't see the connection between $1$, $5$, $7$, and $11$ and how they have multiplicative inverses in $Z_{12}$

The zero divisors of $Z_{12}$ make sense. $6*2=0$. And neither $6$ nor $2$ are 0.

Answer (score 3):

The units in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ are those numbers $a$ satisfying $\gcd(a, m) = 1$.

By [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), $\gcd(a, m) = 1 \iff$ there are numbers $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:

$$ax + my = 1$$

And so, modding out by $m$, we get:

$$ax \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$$

And thus, $x \pmod{m}$ is the multiplicative inverse for $a$.  We conclude that $a$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_m \iff a$ and $m$ are coprime.